# Page view events doesn't have userEngagementDuration value in GA 4

Tags: google-analytics, google-analytics-4

We are trying to pull Google Analytic tracking data using GA 4 API. Looks like page view events don't have userEngagementDuration value. it is always returning 0.

Ex. In universal analytic, we usually have
"metrics":[
{
"expression":"ga:timeOnPage"
}
]
it returns the page duration of the user on the page. Similar to this in GA4 for page_view, we want the duration. equivalent of ga:timeOnPage in GA4 is userEngagementDuration. But this is coming as "0" even we stay on the page for quite some time.

Is there anything we are missing here? This pageview has coming auto by making it enable through GA configuration.

[image: GA 4 configuration]

Regards
Pravasini